# Xcode compile warnings: This block declaration is not a prototype

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

I am loading dependencies with podfile and, although everything works as expected, I am worried about warnings produced by Xcode.
Is there anything that needs to be done with that?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those warnings come from the dependencies that you included via CocoaPods. Generally, you don't need to do anything because of those warnings.

If you want to fix the underlying issue you should fork the Pod, fix the issue and create a Pull Request afterwards.

If you want to ignore the warnings you can add this to your Podfile. This will result in all warnings coming from Pods to be ignored, so they are not shown in Xcode.

```
# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!
```